# Angular2 Error: EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: typescript, angular

For whatever reason Angular2 is not happy with one of my pages. The other pages seem to work fine. The error that gets produced only on the quinoa pages is:
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Not sure what is causing the error as the project is ultra small right now and as far as I know identical to angular2 Quick Start Guide.

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks!!!

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { MainComponent } from './main.component';

import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

bootstrap(MainComponent, [ Title, ROUTER_PROVIDERS ]);
```

main.component.ts

```
// Import the native Angular services.
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { QuinoaComponent } from './quinoa.component';
import { NaturalHerbsComponent } from './naturalherbs.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'c-main',
    templateUrl: 'app/html/main.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'Home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
        path: '/quinoa',
        name: 'SuperfoodQuinoa',
        component: QuinoaComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/naturalherbs',
        name: 'NaturalHerbs',
        component: NaturalHerbsComponent
    }
])

export class MainComponent {
    /*public constructor( private titleService: Title ) { }

    public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
        this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
    }*/
}
```

The erroring component:
quinoa.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'c-quinoa',
    templateUrl: 'app/html/quinoa.component.html'
})

export class QuinoaComponent { }
```

Comment: It seems to be erroring out in the html. As if I just have a <div></div> tag nothing errors but as soon as I place some actual content it errors.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the editor I am using gives a pop-up asking if it can indent for you and for some reason angularjs 2 does not like it.

The editor I am using is webstorm 2016.